# Setting system property from code.

Tags: java

my question is how dangerous is the use of `System.setProperty(“https.protocols”, “TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2”);` from code. And how to avoid it ? Is there any better way ? And if it is related to `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`  can You please explain because I tried every blog or discussion and I still don't get where to type this command. Should it be in cmd ? From where ? Should I add it in some Java bin conf file ? What is the best practice of this kind of things. It is related to java 1.7 and protocol TLSv1.2   Thank You.

Comment: First you need to read up on what is `TLS`. Once you know how it works then you can workout why you need to set it and what components/classes use it. Your asking lots of questions here. Consider asking 1 question per thread.

Comment: You type the "command" when you run your code, e.g. if you run from the command-line, you'd do something like `java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -cp /path/to/classes org.example.MyMainClass`. If you use an IDE, you'd specify the option in the VM Arguments field. Exactly where that is depends on the IDE.

Comment: @Minh Kieu Ok. Thank you for advice I will do that. One question is my greatest concern and that is can this cause some issues or problems and what ? It seems a little insecure if i need to set system properties every time when app runs ? Or set it from code and hardcode it.

Comment: You could create a shell script to run your command. Its best to set using the `-D` so that you can change it at anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-D` flag [sets a system property](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/).  Both the `-D` flag and `System.setProperty` are equivalent.

Where and when you set it depends on your application.  If you want to set it as an application parameter, then you may do so with your applications equivalent of `java -Dsystem.property=value MyApp`.  If you want to set this programmatically, then somewhere in your code you'd write `System.setProperty("system.property", "value");`.  At that point, it's a matter of taste.